# Solving System of Nonlinear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This system of differential equations comes with some guiding exploration questions:
\begin{align*} \dfrac{dx}{dt} &= \dfrac{x}{w}, \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} &= \dfrac{xz}{w}, \\ \dfrac{dz}{dt} &= \beta y, \\ \dfrac{dw}{dt} &= \beta y, \end{align*}

> Explore the existence of periodic solutions to this system of equations and the dependence of solutions to this system on initial conditions.  In particular, start by considering $x(0)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}$, $y(0)=2$, $z(0)=w(0)=5\sqrt{5}$. For how long can solutions be extended before uniqueness, and therefore predictability, is lost?  How do the solutions to this system vary qualitatively as we vary $\beta$?

I observed that we have $z=w+C$ and tried simplifying to a single variable differential equation, getting $$\dfrac{C}{w+C} \dfrac{dw}{dt} \dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2} + w\dfrac{d^3w}{dt^3} = \dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2}.$$ After integrating the entire equation and using integration by parts, I got $$\dfrac{C-w}{2(C+w)} \left ( \dfrac{dw}{dt} \right )^2 - \dfrac{dw}{dt} - \dfrac{Cw^2}{2(w+C)} + w\dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2} = C_1,$$ but I can't see a way to go further. I tried integrating the equation again, but it results in $$\dfrac{2w}{w+C} \int \left ( \dfrac{dw}{dt} \right )^2 dt + w + \dfrac{C^3}{2} \ln |w+C| +\dfrac{C}{2} - w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=C_1w+C_2 ,$$ and from what I know and looked up, there's not a way to simplify the integral.

So moving back a step, I tried the subproblem of when $z=w$ and $C=0$. This gives $$ w\dfrac{d^3w}{dt^3} = \dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2}.$$ After integration, we get $$w\dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2}  - \dfrac{1}{2} \left (\dfrac{dw}{dt} \right )^2 - \dfrac{dw}{dt} =C_1.$$ By $S=\dfrac{dw}{dt}$ substitution, I got an autonomous equation and have $$\int \dfrac{S}{\frac{S^2}{2}+S+C_1} dS = \int \dfrac{1}{w} dw.$$ I solved and got $$2\ln \left | \dfrac{S+1}{\sqrt{2}} \right | + \dfrac{2}{S+1} + C_2 = \ln |w| .$$ Finally, since $S=\dfrac{dw}{dt} = \beta y$, I get $$\left |\dfrac{\beta y + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \right |^2 + e^{\frac{2}{\beta y + 1}} + C_3 = w,$$ from which I can extract a lot of information about the behavior as $\beta$ varies from a graph.

Does anyone know how I can do this for the general case or maybe give some insight into its behavior? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You don't need to find actual solutions. Go look at the theorems about existence and uniqueness of solutions. Under what conditions does the uniqueness result hold? In particular, under what conditions can it fail? Where do those coniditions  arise in this problem? For the other question, it is a bit of a guess what "qualitative" variations are they looking for, but I would look at how the solutions differ when $\beta$ is positive, negative or $0$, and generalities about how the solution changes as $\beta$ increases/decreases.